# Tap Gesture Event not Firing on UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm attempting to implement a tap-gesture recognizer on a UIImageView.  However I can't get the method that handles the tap event to fire.  I've compared my code against the answers to many similar questions on stackoverflow but still the problem persists.  Below is the relevant code from my application.  Can someone show me what I've done wrong?

ViewController.h

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *topLeftImage;

-(IBAction)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gestureView;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    topLeftImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [topLeftImage addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    NSLog(@"Tap detected.  Booyah!");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead. You put your code in viewDidUnload, completely the wrong place. You want viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    topLeftImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [topLeftImage addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

}
```

Comment: How embarrassing! I just burned a lot of time on that silly mistake.  Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Your welcome. When you have double checked the code many times, and things are still not working they way you want, I always set a breakpoint to make sure that code is actually getting called.